# No se visualizan los datos en datatable vuejs

Tags: vue.js, datatables

Estoy desarrollando un spa en vuejs y para mostrar los datos utilizo dataTables, tengo los botones de crear un nuevo registro, editar y ver la información y estoy realizando uso de modales, pero estoy presentando problemas en el modo responsive en dispositivos móviles no se me visualizan los datos y a la hora de abrir el modal de editar no me abre tampoco, solo abre el modal de crear.

**Template:**

```
<template>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-auto mr-auto">
                            <h2 class="text-secondary">Lista de Usuarios</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <button class="right btn btn-primary btn-sm" v-b-modal.modal-1 @click="showModal = true">Agregar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-header -->
                <div class="card-body">
                    <table id="tblUser" class="table table-bordered table-hover dt-responsive">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Usuario</th>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Perfil</th>
                                <th>Estado</th>
                                <th>Opciones</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr v-for="(user, index) in users" :key="index">
                                <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
                                <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
                                <td>{{ user.profile }}</td>
                                <td class="activate" v-if="user.deleted_at == null">Activado</td>
                                <td class="desactivate" v-else>Desactivado</td>
                                <td>
                                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Detalle</button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" v-b-modal.editUser @click="editUser(user)" >Editar</button>                                        
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.card -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
    </div>

<!-- Modal Para Agregar Usuarios -->
<AddUser ref="userModal" @reload="getUsers"></AddUser>

<!-- Modal Para Editar Usuarios -->
<EditUser ref="editModal" :editUser="this.dataEditUser" :statusUser="this.status" @reload="getUsers"></EditUser>

</div>
```

**Script:**

```
<script>

// Services
import * as userService from '../../services/user';
// Components
import AddUser from '../../components/Admin/AddUser.vue';
import EditUser from '../../components/Admin/EditUser.vue';
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            users: [],
            dataEditUser: {},
            status: ''
        }
    },
    mounted() {            
        this.getUsers();
    },
    components: {
        AddUser,
        EditUser
    },
    methods: {
        dataTable() {
            this.$nextTick(() => {
                $('#tblUser').DataTable({
                    "ordering": false,
                    // "columnDefs": [
                    //     { "width": "5%", "targets": 3 }
                    // ],
                    language: {
                        "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
                        "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                        "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
                        "sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
                        "sInfo": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                        "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                        "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                        "sInfoPostFix": "",
                        "sSearch": "Buscar:",
                        "sUrl": "",
                        "sInfoThousands": ",",
                        "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                        "oPaginate": {
                            "sFirst": "Primero",
                            "sLast": "Último",
                            "sNext": "Siguiente",
                            "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                        },
                        "oAria": {
                            "sSortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                            "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
                        }
                    },
                });
            });
        },
        
        getUsers: async function() {
            try {
               
                const response = await userService.getUsers();                               
                if(response.status == 200) {
                    this.users = response.data.data;
                    this.reloadTable();                            
                }
            } catch (error) {
                 console.log(error);
                if (error.response.status == 422){
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }
        }, 
        editUser(user) {
            this.dataEditUser = user;
            if (user.deleted_at == null) {
                this.status = 'Activado';
            }else {
                this.status = 'Desactivado';
            }
        },
            reloadTable() {
            $('#tblUser').DataTable().destroy();               
            this.dataTable();
        },
        makeToast(title, text, type) {                
            this.$bvToast.toast(text, {
                title: title,
                variant: type,
                autoHideDelay: 4000,
                appendToast: true,
                solid: true
            })
        },
        
    }
}
```

**Librerias que tengo para dataTable:**

```
    //Bootstrap
require('./bootstrap');
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css';
import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue';

//DataTables
import 'datatables.net-bs4';
import 'datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js';
import 'datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css';
import 'datatables.net-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js';
import 'datatables.net-responsive-bs4/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css';
import 'datatables.net-responsive-bs4/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js';

//Rutas
import router from './routes';

Vue.use(BootstrapVue);

const app = new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 store,
 router,
});
```

**Imagen en dispositivo móvil**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado cambiar de versión de dataTables y agregando la clase dt-responsive a la tabla pero no se me visualizan los datos en mobile.

Gracias

Comment: ouch.. jquery mezclado con vue.. es un no no... vue usa un dom virtual.. que no se lleva nada pero nada bien con jquery.. vendra por ahi tu problema??? Igual veo que usas bootstrap.. hay algo de la tabla de bootstrap que no te alcance?????

Comment: Ok, no sabia esa parte, ya la corregí pero aún así no se me visualizan los datos, las columnas no se adaptan correctamente en modo responsive

Comment: de cuales columnas hablas? como es el css? podrias mostar un ejemplo del problema? en este caso si valen imagenes...

Comment: Listo, edite la pregunta y agregue una imagen de como se ve en dispositivos móviles la tabla, gracias

Comment: Porque estas eliminando un objeto de la pantalla y volviendolo a crear? deja esa tarea a vue.. puede ser por eso que no ves datos? NO TOQUES EL DOM...

Comment: En que parte del code mencionas, me podes indicar ?

Comment: que hace todo esto? reloadTable() {
            $('#tblUser').DataTable().destroy();               
            this.dataTable();

Comment: Recarga la tabla, ya elimine ese código pero sigue presentando el mismo problema

Comment: Porque recargas algo? vue lo hace solo eso... las variables son reactivas, vos no tenes que recargar nada... tal vez necesites una implementacion de datatables para vue? la buscaste?

Comment: proba en lugar de esto: this.users = response.data.data; hacer Object.set(this.users,response.data.data) y te fijaste que en tu data viniera algo, no?

Comment: Ok, lo intentare con otra implementación de datatables para vue, muchas gracias

Comment: @Desarrollador pudiste resolver el problema, porque yo presento dicho error, cuando la página está maximizada los datos en el modal se muestran, pero en versión móvil no, parece que al ocultarse ciertas columnas, no las muestra en el modal, alguna idea ??

Comment: @LOPUMAJoseAlvaroCedeño Agrege un div dentro del card body con la clase table-responsive, asi  <div class="card-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="example">

Comment: Ok, probaré gracias.